# Schedule Message sending through AlarmManager class.At The Second time my AlarlManager get overwrite

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Hi everyone making an app for auto reply and i have set some delay in message sending  on Broadcast of missed call through AlarmManager class.

It get override if i got the two missed calls symulteneosely.how i can fix it plese help.

here is my alarmManager on missed call broadcast

```
private void sendSMSWithDelay(String number, String responseMessage,
            int delayInResponce) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Global.getMyApplicationContext(),
                MyCallBroadcastReceiver.class);
        // Intent i = new Intent(MessageService.this,
        // ViewMessageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("number", number);
        intent.putExtra("message", responseMessage);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                Global.getMyApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Global
                .getMyApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Global.getMyApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (delayInResponce * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);

    }
```

Comment: I want to send message each time

Comment: No, its not working till now it overwite from the second missed call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
private void sendSMSWithDelay(String number, String responseMessage,
            int delayInResponce) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Global.getMyApplicationContext(),
                MyCallBroadcastReceiver.class);
        // Intent i = new Intent(MessageService.this,
        // ViewMessageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("number", number);
        intent.putExtra("message", responseMessage);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                Global.getMyApplicationContext(), new Random().nextLong(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Global
                .getMyApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Global.getMyApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (delayInResponce * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

For example:- alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
       System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (delayInResponce * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);